# A fundamental question on 'which'

Tags: commas

A very simple but confusing question, really.

I see a sentence in my past paper that goes,

> Ben intended to use the cars for his business in Egypt, where he had his place of business which was known to Jim before the conclusion of the contract.

I wonder what Jim knew - the fact that Ben intended to use the cars for business, or that the he had his place of business in Egypt?

Comment: He knew that whoever was writing this was a very poor writer.

Comment: To me, it means that Jim knew Ben's "place of business" . But not exactly "place of business in Egypt". However, that the known place  was in Egypt is implicit to the knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

The most likely interpretation is that the antecedent of "which" here is "his place of business." That is: *his place of business* is what was known to Jim.

Comment: Hot Licks' response is the most appropriate. Attempts to decipher poorly written script are at best opinion, and do not fit with the supported answer format desired on ELU. FWIW, I'd guess at 'Ben intended to use the cars for his business in Egypt, where he had his place of business ... this intention was known to Jim before the conclusion of the contract.'